# New Skeptics.SE Podcast

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, podcast

[image]

*Wouldn't it be nice to have a bi-weekly podcast in which to chat about this site and its great answers?*

It would be nice, indeed!

[Larian](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/386/larian-lequella) and I are creating a podcast for skeptics.se. It will be aired every 2 weeks and will include discussion on the best questions and answers of the period, announcements and guests.

We would like to invite the community to be involved in the production, so if you are able to help, please register your availability [on this google form](http://goo.gl/forms/ZVT3Ob40mu).

<sup>This is a completely *unofficial* initiative to come together as a community.</sup>

What would you like to hear about on this podcast?

---

Update: the podcast is available [here](http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:2636145/sounds.rss). We've applied to iTunes and Tune In, but we are still pending.

Comment: I look forward to listening.  Something that I would be interested in hearing is how many people we are reaching (what questions come up in google searches, how do we rank on them, etc.).

Comment: Would definitely be interested in this.

Answer (score 6):

The first episode has now been released.

- https://soundcloud.com/user9210836/skeptics-stack-exchange-podcast-s01-e01
- http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/skeptics-stack-exchange-podcast
- http://tunein.com/radio/Skeptics-Stack-Exchange-Podcast-p869154/

Feel free to comment and suggest improvements. If you want to participate, register your interest here: http://goo.gl/forms/ZVT3Ob40mu

Comment: Very cool podcast, but the constant music in the background is very distracting.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: negative. I find it non-awkward and it makes the whole thing more entertaining.

Comment: The constant music is not standard and distracted me. Usually podcasts will talk over music only in intros or outros or during advertisement.

Comment: Good feedback. I will tone it down a notch or two. It's fairly common in radio.